# How to initialize the JGroups AUTH protocol programmatically

Tags: java, jgroups

I try to initialize the `AUTH` protocol programmatically but keep getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field auth_class not found`.

Obviously `AUTH.java` doesn't have the field `auth_class` though there is a setter annotated with this property.
Here is a snippet of the protocol stack:

```
new ASYM_ENCRYPT()
        .setValue("use_external_key_exchange", true)
        .setValue("encrypt_entire_message", true)
        .setValue("sym_keylength", 256)
        .setValue("sym_algorithm", "AES")
        .setValue("asym_keylength", 512)
        .setValue("asym_algorithm", "RSA"),
new AUTH()
        .setValue("auth_class", "org.jgroups.auth.X509Token")
        .setValue("keystore_path", "/tmp/cert.jks")
        .setValue("keystore_password", "changeit")
        .setValue("cert_alias", "mycert")
        .setValue("cert_password", "changeit")
        .setValue("auth_value", "secret")
        .setValue("cipher_type", "RSA"),
new GMS()
        .setValue("print_local_addr", true)
        .setValue("join_timeout", 2000)
```

So how can I initialize `AUTH` with `X509Token` and appropriate properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auth_class` is not an attribute, so you'll have to use the setter:

`AUTH auth=new AUTH()
                  .setValue("keystore_path", "/tmp/cert.jks")
                  .setValue("keystore_password", "changeit")
                  .setValue("cert_alias", "mycert")
                  .setValue("cert_password", "changeit")
                  .setValue("auth_value", "secret")
                  .setValue("cipher_type", "RSA");
          auth.setAuthClass("org.jgroups.auth.X509Token");`